# Getting a List from a Swing Textbox

Tags: java, swing, list, textbox

I am trying to get a list input from a user using the Swing GUI. Is it possible to get a list within a textbox? for example, the user would write

> 132, 234, 76, 14, 9

Which I would hold into an Array to be used later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get a `String` via `Textfield#getText` and then you can use `String#split` with the delimiter you want. Note that the delimiter is a [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the TextField you used has variable name `textbox`,

```
    String textboxValue = textbox.getText();//where textboxValue would equal to 132, 234, 76, 14, 9
    String [] numbers = textboxValue.split(",");//Stored in this array using regular expression (regex) in java

    for (String number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(""+number);
    }
```